# What is a PGP Secret Key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, pgp, secret-key

I am working on a C# app that encrypts/decrypts messages using PGP implemented by the Bouncy Castle (BC) library.  I know PKI but the secret key in PGP throws me off a bit.  I looked at the BC examples/source code and the PGP RFC but came away with more questions.

Is Secretkey == Session key?

Is Secretkey == Symmetric key?

Is Secretkey == private key (pub/priv key pairs)?  At least the following seems to suggest that the secret key is a private key.

```
internal static PgpPrivateKey FindSecretKey(PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec, long keyID, char[] pass)
```

The RFC says the secretkey contains, among others, information about the publickey or may be the public key itself (at least that's my reading).

Also, somewhere I read the Secretkey is basically a password encrypted privatekey.

When/why would I need a secret key in the PGP protocol? Signing or encrypting?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 5.5.1.3. Secret-Key Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.5.1.3):

> A Secret-Key packet contains all the information that is found in a
> Public-Key packet, including the public-key material, but also
> includes the secret-key material after all the public-key fields.

and [11.2. Transferable Secret Keys](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-11.2):

> [...] The format of a transferable
> secret key is the same as a transferable public key except that
> secret-key and secret-subkey packets are used instead of the public
> key and public-subkey packets.  Implementations SHOULD include self-
> signatures on any user IDs and subkeys, [...]

With other words, the secret key contains the public/private key pair (eg., RSA), but should also contain user IDs and self-signatures. [12.1. Key Structures](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-12.1) gives more details on how exported keys are constructed. A helpful tool for understanding the composition of OpenPGP packets are `gpg --list-packets [file]` or `pgpdump [file]`, which dump the packet structure of their input.

Comment: I want to make this as the answer but don't know how.

Comment: There's a small gray checkmark on the left next to the vote triangles, which you can click to select an answer. There's also a description in the [FAQ].